# Is there a way using only CSS to hide an element when other is displayed?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="content">   
    <div id="loading-bar-container"></div>
        <div data-ng-view> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently the `div` with the id `loading-bar-container` is automatically displayed while the page is loading and hidden when the page is fully loaded (it is a loading bar). This is achieved by changing dinamically the value of CSS property `display` for this element using JQuery.

Now I want also that while the loading bar is displayed, the div below (`div data-ng-view`) is automatically hidden so this div is not displayed till the page is loaded.
I would like to achieve this behaviour using only CSS+HTML.

Comment: You can select sibling elements with CSS, but CSS can not really “check” on the state of whether an element is currently getting displayed or not. (It _might_ perhaps work, if the display property is set as an inline style, using the attribute selector. But that would be quite fiddly, and bound to easily break apart, should something else ever add other inline styles.)

Comment: Can you alter the jquery to set a class on the loading-bar-container instead of altering its style directly? That way its sibling data-ng-view can pick it up and be displayed using just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the top parent element like this:

```css
.content #loading-bar-container {
  display: none;
}
.content > div[data-ng-view] {
  display: block;
}

.content.is-loading #loading-bar-container {
  display: block;
}
.content.is-loading > div[data-ng-view] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Toggle 'is-loading' class on loading, and remove it after loaded -->
<div class="content is-loading">   
    <div id="loading-bar-container">Loading</div>
    <div data-ng-view>Loaded</div>
</div>
```